# Syncing All Subscribers with Salesforce Leads

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have mapped my profile attributes with the Lead object in Salesforce.
I am struggling to understand how the All Subscribers will be synced with Lead object?

I want a new subscriber to be created in MC as soon as a new lead is created in SFDC. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscriber will only be created in Marketing once a message is sent. So either sending to a report/campaign, executing a triggered send or injecting someone into a Journey.
Whereas there are different ways to get Leads/Contacts and other objects into a Marketing Cloud Data Extension (e.g. Import Activities, Data Streams) a send out to a lead/contact is necessary to have a subscriber be created in the All Subscriber List.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible workaround to immediately have a new lead or contact created in SFMC All Subscribers. When you create a workflow in Sales Cloud which automatically unsubscribes a new Lead, the record will be synched immediately to All Subscribers List (with status unsubscribed). You would need to setup another workflow in SFMC to Re-Subscribe that Lead in All-Subscribers List, after your Synch from SF to SFMC was conducted.